# Cracks between ortho images when floating on 3D surface - ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, imagery, visualisation, arcscene

I am trying to create a seamless 3D visualisation in ArcScene 10.1. I have a TIN surface created from 1m contour lines. I have 4 tiles of ortho imagery I would like to drape over the surface. So far I have been using the Base Heights tab in the properties dialog box on the images to "float on a custom surface" so that the imagery takes on the 3D shape of the TIN surface.

However, the result is that most of the image looks great draped over the surface except where the images come together, I get a very jagged seam, as if data is missing. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I have tried increasing the layer offset to see if I could raise the images above any noise or elevation irregularities but it doesn't make a difference, I still get the seam gaps.

When displayed flat (not floating on custom surface) the images fit together perfectly with no gaps.

How can I display this imagery in 3D using ArcScene or other software so that it appears seamless and without gaps?

Comment: Mosaic them into single image

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had originally tried importing the rasters into a mosaic dataset but mosaic datasets can't be used in ArcScene. After seeing your post I realised I could just make one raster out of them all and found an ArcTool called 'Mosaic to New Raster' which worked perfectly. Not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place - sometimes it just takes someone looking at it with a fresh perspective. Thanks heaps for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @FelixIP you can simply

> Mosaic them into single image

to avoid this problem.